# How I can add a control to a hand rig for easy hand poses?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

like as subject I would add a control to my hand rig to easy animate a flat hand to a fist. For example a bone that when scaled, all fingers make a fist.

Edit: This is what I would like to achieve:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may do it using a ***Copy Rotation bone constraints*** and ***drivers***.
[image]

I'll show you how to do it using one finger and then you may implement it to the whole hand. Add the ***Copy Rotation constraint*** to last two bones, so the lower bone copies the middle bone rotation and then middle bone copies the top bone rotation.

[image]

Set the constraint's *spaces* to *Local*<-->*Local* for each constrained bone. Now, when you rotate the upper bone the other ones follow to create a fist.
[image]

Add a *circle* (it may be a *bone* with a *custom shape* or other object). It'll be your controller. Select the top bone (the one without the constraint), go to the *Transform* panel and add a driver to the rotation value (in my case a Z axis rotation). Hover the cursor over the value, press the <kbd>RMB</kbd>-->***Add Single Driver***. Go to the *Graph Editor* and set its mode to ***Drivers***. Press <kbd>N</kbd> to open the *properties panel*. In *Drivers* panel choose the ***Transform Channel*** and ***Average Value*** options, set the *circle* as a controller in the *Object/Bone* window. Change the *space* to ***Local*** and *type* to ***Scale***. Use ***Generator*** modifier to adjust things. Press ***Update Dependencies*** button at the end. Now scaling the circle affects the rotation of the bones.
[image]

Comment: Awesome. Thank you Paul Gonet. Do you know some tutorial that cover this genres of things?

Comment: Hello. Sorry for a late reply, but I wasn't home. I learned about it from the dvd from here: http://www.cgmasters.net/training-dvds/character-creation-rigging/ It's not free, but worth every penny as it teaches you a lot of useful stuff. I guess you may find some free tutorials on YT about it, but you'll have to search a bit.